# On Ajax post of ASP.NET form, the control values are all blank?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, post

I'm making an ajax POST to this url using jQuery like this :

```
var url = '/Actions/NewBlog.aspx?m=ajax';
$.ajax({        
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: { txt : con },
    success: function () {
        $('#divDraftMsg').show();            
    },
    dataType: 'text'
});
```

Then on the server side , I want to read the values of the controls. Here's my code for that part :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["m"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["m"]))
        {
            SaveDraft();
            Response.Clear();
            return;
        }
    }

    private void SaveDraft()
    {
        BlogInfo blogInfo = new BlogInfo();
        blogInfo.Content_BD = txtContent.Text + hdnDraft.Value;
        blogInfo.Owner_ND = Profile.StudentID.ToString();
        blogInfo.PostedOn_ND = DateTime.Now;
        blogInfo.SaveDraft();
    }
```

But in the code-behind file, the values of all the controls are blank even though they all have values filled up inside the form(UI) before ajax call. So, what's wrong here???

Also, I'm posting JSON data , but don't know how to read it from the .cs file???

Comment: Use this `data: $('form').serialize();` It will do all the job for.

Comment: :) already did it. I was just worried about the "amount" of data that can be posted in this way.

Comment: If i'm not wrong, there is no limitation because it's a POST request, the data doesn't must be in the `queryString` it can be in the params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass values using `data` and access those as querystring parameters. in this case,
`Request.QueryString["txt"]`

Comment: if you are using ajax request, you have to pass required data through the query string(same as `data`) form fields are only available for postback. [for more info](http://cmsnsoftware.blogspot.com/search/label/Ajax)

Comment: As I guess, there are some restrictions on the amount of data that can be sent through querystrings and it's not very large.
what if the values to be posted are too long for a querystring???

Comment: nope. that's same as the form submit. you can select get or post or any type.